# Python class updates original dict when reassigned inside class

Tags: python, python-3.7

I've been stuck with this issue for a while and can't seem to understand what is going on here. When I pass in an object, in this case a dict, the class seems to use the same dict in memory and updates the original dict even though I assign it to a different variable.

Example:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, dict_b):
        self.dict_a = dict_b

    def update(self, stuff):

        for s in stuff:
            self.dict_a['list'].append(s)
        return self


my_dict = {"list": []}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass(my_dict)

    print(my_dict)
    print(myclass.dict_a)

    myclass.update([1,2,3])

    print("after update")

    print(my_dict)
    print(myclass.dict_a)
```

This outputs

```
{'list': []}
{'list': []}
after update
{'list': [1, 2, 3]}
{'list': [1, 2, 3]}
```

when it should output

```
{'list': []}
{'list': []}
after update
{'list': []}
{'list': [1, 2, 3]}
```

What would be the reason for `my_dict` getting updated?

The only solution I found thus far is to use deepcopy:

```
self.dict_a = copy.deepcopy(dict_b)
```

Using python3.7

Comment: "even though I assign it to a different variable" - you have a different variable, but you don't have a different dict. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

python passes things around "by reference" so you aren't making a copy of the dict like you think you are. normally I would suggest the built in `copy` method of the dict class, but since you have a list in there the copy would make a copy of the dict but still only copy the reference of the list in it! so you need to use deep copy!

```
from copy import deepcopy

def __init__(self, dict_b):
        self.dict_a = deepcopy(dict_b)
```

in the future be very careful when passing around mutables (lists and dicts mostly)

Comment: Yes, this does work but it feels quite unnecessary to add this additional import? But your answer does make sense though. Thank you

Comment: because you are using mutables as values in your dict you will either have to copy them manually or use deep copy. i recommend deep copy because the alternative will require you to know exactly what your dict looks like or to implement deepcopy yourself..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code -

class MyClass:

```
def __init__(self, dict_b):
    self.dict_a = {"list": list(dict_b["list"])}

def update(self, stuff):

    for s in stuff:
        self.dict_a['list'].append(s)
    return self


my_dict = {"list": []}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass(my_dict)

    print(my_dict)
    print(myclass.dict_a)

    myclass.update([1,2,3])

    print("after update")

    print(my_dict)
    print(myclass.dict_a)
```

And here is the output -

```
{'list': []}
{'list': []}
after update
{'list': []}
{'list': [1, 2, 3]}
>>>
```

Watch the change in constructor, you must use the list() function to make a copy of the list that is different from the original list. If you just assign a list to another list, both the list refer to a common list, so, when you change either of them, the affect is seen on the other. They are just like alias to each other.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but why would it not work if I use```self.dict_a = dict(dict_b)```

Comment: I don't know accurately but it appears (90 %) that the key in  self.dict_a is assigned the list i.e. the list constructor is not invoked and thus the lists in both the dictionaries refer to the same list in memory.